# Which SignalR dependency injection method is preferable?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

As I understand, there two ways to implement custom dependency injection in SignalR.

The first one involves replacing GlobalHost.DependencyResolver like

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container); //in case of Autofac
```

Another way is to specify Resolver as part of config passed to app.MapSignalR:

```
app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration { Resolver = resolver });
```

But how do these two ways coexist? Do they differ in any meaningful way? Do I need to specify both resolvers? Even official [SignalR documentation on Dependency Injection](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) mentions both methods without specifying the difference (or I missed it). That's extremely confusing.

Comment: if you want to go for IoC the you need to implement the `DefaultDependencyResolver` as described under `Replace the SignalR Dependency Resolver` in your link

Comment: Which of two dependency resolvers?

Comment: the `NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver` which is just a wrapper to the kernel.

Comment: But Autofac documentation uses the opposite approach (specifying GlobalHost.DependencyResolver): http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html

Comment: You can do that but I find it easier to replace it for the signalr hubs instead for everything else.

Comment: Why is it easier? It seems like setting one property in both cases

Comment: Only the hubs go over the wrapper to be resolved. If you do the first implementatuon everything else then the hubs get resolved over a wrapper. I just like it more eaven if the gains and pains are almost the same

Comment: Here's a [quick SignalR and Autofac sample I put together a while back](https://github.com/radu-matei/signalr-dependency-injection-autofac), hope it helps!